# Writing SQL to U-SQL Query

Tags: u-sql

Can anybody please guide me in writing this below SQL in U-SQL language used in Azure Data Lake

```
select tt.userId, count(tt.userId) from (SELECT userId,count(userId) as cou
  FROM [dbo].[users]

  where createdTime> DATEADD(wk,-1,GETDATE())

   group by userId,DATEPART(minute,createdTime)/5) tt group by tt.userId
```

I don't find the DATEPART function in U-SQL . Azure Data Analytic job is giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U-SQL does not provide T-SQL intrinsic functions except for a few (like LIKE). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621343.aspx for a list.

So how do you do DateTime operations? You just use the C# functions and methods!

So `DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE())` is something like `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)`
and
`DATEPART(minute,createdTime)/5` (there is an extra `)` in your line) is something like `createdTime.Minute/5` (maybe you need to cast it to a double if you want non-integer value).

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who is looking for the implementation mentioned by Michael. It's like below

```
@records =
    EXTRACT userId   string,                      
            createdTime DateTime            
    FROM "/datalake/input/data.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();

 @result =
    SELECT
        userId,       
        COUNT(createdTime) AS userCount
    FROM @records
    WHERE createdTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
GROUP BY userId,createdTime.Minute/5;

@result2= SELECT userId,COUNT(userId) AS TotalCount
 FROM @result
 GROUP BY userId;

OUTPUT @result2 
    TO "/datalake/output/data.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```